# Couchbase returns A design document may only contain mapreduce or spatial views couchbase error when creating mapreduce view and spatial view together

Tags: java, sdk, couchbase

I am trying to execute following code from couchbase documentation but getting this error.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .connectTimeout(100000) //10000ms = 10s, default is 5s
            .build();
    CouchbaseCluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env,"127.0.0.1");
    Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("travel-sample");

    BucketManager bucketManager = bucket.bucketManager();

    DesignDocument designDoc = DesignDocument.create(
            "landmarks",
            Arrays.asList(
                    DefaultView.create("by_country",
                            "function (doc, meta) { if (doc.type == 'landmark') { emit([doc.country, doc.city], null); } }"),
                    DefaultView.create("by_activity",
                            "function (doc, meta) { if (doc.type == 'landmark') { emit(doc.activity, null); } }",
                            "_count"),
                    SpatialView.create("by_coordinates",
                            "function (doc, meta) { if (doc.type == 'landmark') { emit([doc.geo.lon, doc.geo.lat], null); } }")
            )
    );

    bucketManager.insertDesignDocument(designDoc);

}
```

but getting this error "A design document may only contain mapreduce or spatial views". Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 2 functions, DefaultView.create and SpatialView.create

In earlier versions of Couchbase Server when Spatial Views were developer preview this would have worked.  When Spatial Views were introduced as GA in 4.0 there was a restriction added that you can't have both Map Reduce Views and Spatial Views in the same Design Document.

You need to use 2 different Design Documents, 1 for Map Reduce "Default" views and another for Spatial views.

See https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/MB-15256
I've also gone ahead and created https://issues.couchbase.com/browse/DOC-1836 to get the documentation fixed.